# masm32 перестал видеть папку с INC-файлами

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

В общем, я не знаю что произошло, но у меня вдруг перестала работать опция /I (путь к include-файлам) в ml. Раньше всё работало, теперь выдаёт ошибку типа такого:

```
pe.asm(8) : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : WINDOWS.INC
```

В исходнике указано имя файла без пути:

```
INCLUDE     WINDOWS.INC
```

Файл этот точно есть и точно по указанному пути.
Если установить переменную окружения INCLUDE=этому пути или задать полный путь в исходнике, всё ок.

Но это ещё не всё. Линкер тоже выдаёт (даже если прописать в исходнике полные пути к lib'ам):

```
D:\pe.obj : warning LNK4033: converting object format from OMF to COFF
pe.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess@4
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup
pe.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Т.е. ощущение, что не только /I перестало работать, но и /coff, например. Да и lib'ы почему-то не линкуются, судя по всему...

Переустановка masm32 не помогает... Пробовал подменить даже содержимое папки bin (версия 6.14) файлами версии 6.11 (скачанной из инета) - та же ерунда. Т.е. проблема явно не в компиляторе самом, а в чём - ума не приложу! Загадка какая-то!

Понимаю, что инфы мало, но даже не знаю что ещё сообщить. Всё, что было сделано (перед тем, как проблема появилась) - это компиляция пары исходников через ml64. Попытка установить MASMsetup.EXE, скачанный с сайта Microsoft (но вышла ошибка "MS Visual C++ Express Edition 2005 required" и забил на это). Ну ещё я случайно скопировал несколько *.lib-файлов для 64 бит в папку lib для 32 бит (без замены, но потом удалил эти файлы). Обновление Notepad ++ я уж не беру в расчёт. Но в любом случае, повторюсь, masm32 (скачанный с masm32.com) я переустанавливал!

**Что делать?**

p.s. Исходник пустой:

```
.586P
.MODEL Flat,StdCall
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE

INCLUDE     WINDOWS.INC
INCLUDE     KERNEL32.INC
INCLUDE     USER32.INC
INCLUDELIB  KERNEL32.LIB
INCLUDELIB  USER32.LIB

.CODE

Start:

        invoke  ExitProcess, NULL

END     Start
```

**upd**: Поменял ml на 8-ю версию и вместо /I стал менять переменную окружения include (в bat-нике). Всё заработало.
Но всё же, мне не понятна причина этих проблем... Совсем недавно всё работало с версией 6.14 (из пакета masm32)...

Comment: `мне не понятна причина этих проблем` — по каким-то причинам исчезли параметры, указывающие пути к папкам с включаемыми и и библиотечными файлами по умолчанию. Переустановка же не помогает, потому что большинство анинсталлеров удаляют только файлы самой программы, оставляя настройки нетронутыми.

Comment: Единственное, что могу посоветовать — поискать в реестре и `C:\Users\<имя пользователя>\AppData` упоминание `masm`, удалить их и переустановить MASM.

Comment: @Arhad, masm32 ничего (существенного) не пишет в реестр, тем более: а) я же прописываю пути в ключе /I, б) указание пути через переменную окружения работает (но линкует только после компиляции через 8-ю версию), в) после первоначальной переустановки (давно) я перенёс весь masm32 в другое место, и всё работало прекрасно.